# Selection change on different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

Hi i'm trying to find a solution to a problem concerning the selection change event:
i have a worksheet with a list of products and all the details related. on another worksheet i have the same products with other info. what i would like to do is clicking on the product cell in the first sheet,havinf it filtered in the second one. the ON/OFF option is to enable/disable this functionality in the file which already has a double-click enabled macro. thanks for looking into it

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngF As Range
    Dim rngFS As Range

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Set rngF = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    Set rngFS = ActiveSheet.Range("FilterStatus")

    lCol = rngF.Columns(1).Column - 1
    lRow = rngF.Columns(1).Row

    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

    If Target.Address = rngFS.Address Then
      If rngFS.Value = "On" Then
        rngFS.Value = "Off"
      Else
        rngFS.Value = "On"
      End If
    End If

    If UCase(rngFS.Value) = "ON" Then
      If Not Intersect(Target, rngF) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > lRow Then
          rngF.AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column - lCol, _
              Criteria1:=Target.Value
        ElseIf Target.Row = lRow Then
          rngF.AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column - lCol
        End If
      End If
    End If

    exitHandler:
      Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

Comment: What and where is the current problem in your code?

Comment: Logic : `1` Declare a worksheet object (Say wsAF) in your code. Assign the worksheet where you actually want to use autofilter to this worksheet object `2` In the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` of list of products worksheet, simply perform the autofilter using wsAF.Rng.Autofiler

Comment: the current problem is i have sheet1 where in column A i have a list of names. in Sheet2 i have column C containing the same names so what i would like to do is clicking on one cell on Sheet1 column A and have that value filtered on Sheet2 column C.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth but i'm trying to and cannot make it, the code was already in the file and i'm not able to do this change in the code. can you please help?